# javascript workshop_utils.js(114): SyntaxError: missing name after . operator if (funcs.default) { ....................^

Tags: javascript

I am getting the following when running jsl

```
workshop_utils.js(114): SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
      if (funcs.default) {
....................^
```

Here is the relevant code

```
if (funcs.default) {
return funcs.default(data, type, row);
```

Comment: We have no idea what the rest of your js file looks like...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "default" is a reserved keyword. You can't use it "naked" like that as a property name. You can use it as a string, however:

```
if (funcs["default"]) {
```

(The keyword is part of the syntax for `switch` statements.)